# Azure B2C and azure subscriptions - newbie clarification

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have at some point misunderstood something and need some clarification concerning AzureAD, AzureAD-B2C and Azure subscriptions.

Let us say there is two AzureAD, one for the company and one B2C directory. 
And there is a Azure subscriptions, linked to the companys AzureAD.

And I want to make some applications (azure function etc.), whom uses the B2C login functionality.

**Question:**

As far as I understand the App registration must be in the B2C directory.

But the Subscription, and the subscriptions resources whom uses the B2C functionality. Must the subscription linked directory be B2C?

- or can the linked directory be the companys AAD and the resources can use the B2C funtionallity?

*NB: I am not thinking of Access Control (IAM)*

In advance thanks for any kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "consuming" side of B2C is completely independent of the hosting environment. So you can host that anywhere (even outside azure).

For billing purposes the B2C directory must be linked to a subscription.

Comment: Thanks, now I figured out where I went wrong. I misunderstood the "subscription is required" and should have realized that the reason was billing.